# i want to change the background color of a button once clicked and change again to original color once i click another button

Tags: javascript, css

I am doing `asp.net/c#` tabs including a button. I want to change the color of the button once clicked and after I click another button I want to change the other buttons color and the first one will have the old color, I have used a class on active but it will change it for 1 sec.

This is my `asp.net` code:

```
 <div>
     <input type="button" id="t1" class="button" onclick="setColor('tab1', 0)" value="b 1">
     <input type="button" id="t2" class="button" onclick="setColor('tab2', 1)" value="b 2" >
     <input type="button" id="t3" class="button" onclick="setColor('tab3', 2)" value="b 3">
</div>
```

This is the JavaScript. When I am doing window.location.href it displays the default color again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setColor(btn, par) {
    if (par ==  0) {
        window.location.href = "Default.aspx";
        document.getElementById("tab1").style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
        document.getElementById("tab2").style.backgroundColor = "#00bcd4";
        document.getElementById("tab3").style.backgroundColor = "#00bcd4";  
    } else if (par == 1) {
        window.location.href = "Default2.aspx";
        document.getElementById("tab1").style.backgroundColor = "#00bcd4";
        document.getElementById("tab2").style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
        document.getElementById("tab3").style.backgroundColor = "#00bcd4";
    } else if (par == 2) {
        window.location.href = "Default3.aspx";
        document.getElementById("tab1").style.backgroundColor = "#00bcd4";
        document.getElementById("tab2").style.backgroundColor = "#00bcd4";
        document.getElementById("tab3").style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's a good idea to format your code correctly, both here and in the sources

Comment: Also, please only use relevant tags. This has nothing to do with the backend. Also remove pointelss comments before posting. See how this is more readable after my comment? Think of the person trying to answer your question and decipher what you doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished with a simple CSS rule and no JavaScript at all.

> I have used Cascading style sheet class on active but it will change
>   it for 1 sec.

Your problem was that you tried the `:active` pseudo-class (which, for a button, only applies while the button is "actively" being clicked) instead of the `:focus` pseudo-class.

```css
.button { background-color:aqua; }  /* default color for all buttons */
.button:focus { background-color: rgba(255, 75, 75, .5); }
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <input type = "button" id="tab1" class="button" value ="button 1">
  <input type = "button" id="tab2" class="button" value ="button 2">
  <input type = "button" id="tab3" class="button" value ="button 3">
</div>
```

To keep the button's "focus" color, even when it loses the focus to another non-button element, you'd set up a `click` event handler for each button that adds the same class to the clicked button and removes it from all the others:

```js
// Get all the relevant buttons into an array
var buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".button"));

// Loop through the buttons
buttons.forEach(function(btn){

  // Set up a click event handler for the button
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Loop though all the buttons and reset the colors back to default
    buttons.forEach(function(btn){ btn.classList.remove("focus"); });
    this.classList.add("focus"); // Add the class to the one button that got clicked
  });
  
});
```

```css
.button { background-color:aqua; }  /* default color for all buttons */
.focus { background-color: rgba(255, 75, 75, .5); }
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <input type = "button" id="tab1" class="button" value ="button 1">
  <input type = "button" id="tab2" class="button" value ="button 2">
  <input type = "button" id="tab3" class="button" value ="button 3">
</div>

<p>Other things to click on:
  <input type = "text" value ="button 1">
  <input type = "button" value ="button 2">
  <input type = "radio" value ="button 3">
</p>
```

Comment: where do I put this code ? in c# or java script? and I call the same function on click?

Comment: @BoutrosDouaihy Wrap all of the JavaScript with `<script>` and `</script>` and place the entire `script` in the HTML file, just before the closing `body` tag (`</body>`). No C# needed.

Comment: @BoutrosDouaihy And, of course, put the CSS either in a page-level or external stylesheet (whichever you are using).

Comment: okay now if I want to redirect when clicked to an asp.net page when I click the button where to set the code in this function??

Comment: @BoutrosDouaihy You can add an `if/else` statement inside of the `click` callback function that checks the clicked button's `value` and redirects as needed (i.e. `if(this.value == "button 1"){ location.href = "default1.aspx" } else if(this.value == "button 2")...`.

Comment: I have done it but I encountered another issue , when I redirect to another page the .focus color will disappear again!! how to solve this

Comment: @BoutrosDouaihy That is a completely different issue that is separate from what you asked (as I understood it). In order to persist the color selection across pages, you'll have to store it somewhere. That can be done in a variety of ways, but since you are doing .NET, you may want to use [`ViewState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = "pageName.aspx"
```

makes you go to a another page. In this case the other page loads up. 
This makes you lose the colors that you have set.

You can set the color from code behind to not lose it. Or check which page you are on with window.location.href. And depending on this result set the color onload.

**EDIT:** 
Since you have them on masterpage you can do the following.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SetCurrentPage();
}

private void SetCurrentPage()
{
   var pageName = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
   switch (pageName)
      {
         case "/Default.aspx":
           t1.Attributes["class"] = "button tabColor";
           break;
         case "/Default2.aspx":
            t2.Attributes["class"] = "button tabColor";
            break;
         case "/Default3.aspx":
            t3.Attributes["class"] = "button tabColor";
            break;
      }
}
```

Add `runat="server"` to the controls so you can acces them on code behind.

```
 <div>
     <input type="button" id="t1" runat="server" class="button"  value="b 1">
     <input type="button" id="t2" runat="server" class="button"  value="b 2">
     <input type="button" id="t3" runat="server" class="button"  value="b 3">
</div>
```

Make a css class for the tabcolor

```
.tabColor {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

And to answer your question how to acces a Master control from Child page:

```
var someControl = this.Master.FindControl("controlName");
```

Comment: how to get the button id of and input button from a master page to a child page to be able to set the color their on page load??

Comment: @BoutrosDouaihy: Simple you want to set the active state on your button when the page you navigates to equals the page you're listening for. In this example, if you navigate to "pageName.aspx" you want to set the active state with the button that associates with that button. Once you change pages, "pageName.aspx" will no longer have the active class and your new page will then be active.

Comment: can you please give me an example on how to do activate state??

Comment: what I am supposed to import to use the menu Home in c#?

Comment: menuHome was just a tab already. In your case you use input buttons. I added in the edit what you can do to keep using the buttons. Important is that you add runat="server" so they are accesible from code behind. this way you can set attribute class to whatever class you want.